# Make Postfix add "Authentication-Results" header to locally originated mail destined to local domain?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp-headers, milter, verification

If I write via `sendmail` or SubmissionS client a mail to my virtual account (my domain is example.org), the mail I receive looks like this:

```
Return-Path: <user@example.org>
Delivered-To: user@example.org
Received: from example.org
    by hostname with LMTP
    id 5n+pDaCqAWAOcgAAUprYAg
    (envelope-from <user@example.org>)
    for <user@example.org>; Fri, 15 Jan 2021 15:45:52 +0100
To: user@example.org
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=example.org;
    s=r; t=1610721951;
    h=from:from:reply-to:subject:subject:date:date:message-id:message-id:
     to:to:cc; bh=91RazCIc2UKGe+HBO/tFDtuL2v1Tzk19s+Q44fL6gEY=;
    b=pmlzcXQJAFHqKAjznCT4Hc77BjyX8QFXrQRTfzCH7UXXsBxNYCuSNrM6wSXAZ54+lAVDIO
    MYEGXwY3+4F1GgbJ/dQVQGYq262FKjcVwQhFHALvI704iGMEt5Uu/kqLHkk09EQKIyBlAf
    btrA42do+0lia6kkPNd2ezVqOR8O6WkH52eVKj8x/+lq3P5N4sCgoiOZcnIWUlyBMlhlFa
    vMWLjc+4DU4nLZxOYZyYS68RVJuDN4Vr5cz6+jNGYvidXkCvtyT99MgmMQ38oKwtbpT+0g
    sNzjOif4PbAWrJ+29IoJa/lV9nkYIKVtMa4CPJ6bqAVj4ITjwGLTwswBK//VdA==
From: user@example.org
Subject: test e-mail
Message-Id: <20210115144551.CCFBBA21CC@example.org>
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2021 15:45:51 +0100 (CET)

Mail body
```

If I send it to an external recipient, the "Authentication-Results" is added.

```
Authentication-Results: mail2.outsi.de (dis=neutral; info=dmarc domain policy);
    dmarc=pass (dis=neutral p=reject; aspf=r; adkim=r; pSrc=dns) header.from=example.org;
    dkim=pass header.d=example.org header.s=r header.b=O/8zOi6w
Received: from mail.outsi.de ([10.10.10.11])
        by mail2.outsi.de
        with SMTP (SubEthaSMTP 3.1.7) id KJYEI2ZV
        for user@outsi.de;
        Fri, 15 Jan 2021 15:52:36 +0100 (CET)
Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=10.10.10.10; helo=example.org; envelope-from=user@example.org; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
Received: from example.org (example.org [10.10.10.10])
    by mail1.outsi.de (Postfix) with ESMTPS id ACBEF1060308
    for <user@outsi.de>; Fri, 15 Jan 2021 14:52:36 +0000 (UTC)
To: user@outsi.de
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=example.org;
    s=r; t=1610721951;
    h=from:from:reply-to:subject:subject:date:date:message-id:message-id:
     to:to:cc; bh=91RazCIc2UKGe+HBO/tFDtuL2v1Tzk19s+Q44fL6gEY=;
    b=pmlzcXQJAFHqKAjznCT4Hc77BjyX8QFXrQRTfzCH7UXXsBxNYCuSNrM6wSXAZ54+lAVDIO
    MYEGXwY3+4F1GgbJ/dQVQGYq262FKjcVwQhFHALvI704iGMEt5Uu/kqLHkk09EQKIyBlAf
    btrA42do+0lia6kkPNd2ezVqOR8O6WkH52eVKj8x/+lq3P5N4sCgoiOZcnIWUlyBMlhlFa
    vMWLjc+4DU4nLZxOYZyYS68RVJuDN4Vr5cz6+jNGYvidXkCvtyT99MgmMQ38oKwtbpT+0g
    sNzjOif4PbAWrJ+29IoJa/lV9nkYIKVtMa4CPJ6bqAVj4ITjwGLTwswBK//VdA==
From: user@example.org
Subject: test e-mail
Message-Id: <20210115144551.CCFBBA21CC@example.org>
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2021 15:45:51 +0100 (CET)

Mail body
```

How can I make Postfix add this header even to outgoing mail destined to my local domain (example.org)?
Milter is Rspamd.

In my "main.cf" I have

```
# [...]

non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept
```

In my "master.cf" I have

```
smtp             inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o milter_macro_daemon_name=VERIFYING

submissions      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
 -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

# [...]
```

Comment: What is the goal, why would you add that header containing little to no information that is not already available to every other program that could conceivably care about it?

Comment: @anx Just wondering if it is possible to also verify just signed messages directed to users of a certain domain (mine), and if yes how to do it. From my mail client I would see a green mark next to my locally sent (and received) email, like I already have next to DMARCpassing externally received mail. For now I just see "Signature exists but Authentication-Header doesn't".

Comment: I would expect configuration management to become a bit of a mess but running the same milter twice (first time signing-only, the second time validation-only) should do the trick.

Comment: @anx yes, but do you know how to call rspamd twice using postfix, exactly as you said?

Answer (score 0):

Its becayse your OpenDMARC config has IgnoreAuthenticatedClients set to true
This will ignore emails coming from your local domain.

also looks like you're using Roundcube webmail client with authres_status plugin, for me the workaround was to edit the authres_status.php and detect if the DKIM signatures contains my domain then fake the status to pass xD